# What goes on inside the transistor that amplifies the signal?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, physics, common-emitter

I understand that, for example, in BJT NPN transistor in common emitter configuration used as amplifier, feeding the small signal at the base will produce the larger signal at the collector.

But what goes on inside the transistor that makes the signal come out bigger at the collector ?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question. Someone else may be happy to come along and explain this for you, but have you tried looking this up for yourself? If so what exactly are you confused about? There's tons of articles, textbooks, or even answers on this site that would explain this exact topic for you. Try starting here: https://byjus.com/physics/pnp-transistor/#:~:text=In%20a%20PNP%20transistor%2C%20the%20base%20current%20which,region%20features%20a%20large%20number%20of%20free%20electrons.

Comment: In much of nature, the rate of change in something is related to the current value of that something. Ideal population growth is like that, for example. But this also relates very well to things happening as particles, interacting locally via forces. (Quantum non-locality ignored.) So you might expect to see exponential relationship between voltage and current, for example. The local slope (tangent or secant) at some point on this curve can be used to provide gain.

Comment: Well, it is not the same signal, but another, separate, signal that replicates it, bigger and sometimes inverted. As a matter of fact, what makes amplification (and impedance matching) possible is the decoupling between the input and output meshes. This decoupling is represented in that separation of the meshes in the small signal models of the transistor (and the introduction of a controlled source).